# What's wrong with my login script?

Tags: php

Here is my login.php script.

When it runs, it dumps the array (error 2) of what was input, completely skipping everything (i think). I have absolutely no idea what's wrong.

```
<?php

    include('../../content/php/base.php');

    // Get data
    $user = $_REQUEST['user'];
    $pass = $_REQUEST['pass'];

    // Encrypt password
    include('../../content/php/salt.php');
    $pass = crypt($pass,$salt);

    // Check database for user / check session
    if(!empty($_SESSION['LoggedIn']) && !empty($_SESSION['user'])) {
        header("Location: websiteURL");
    } elseif(!empty($user) && !empty($pass)) {
        $user = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $user);

        if($result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE `user`='".$user."' AND `pass`='".$pass."'")) {
            $row_cnt = mysqli_num_rows($result);
            if($row_cnt == 1) {
                $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);  
                $email = $row['email'];

                $_SESSION['user'] = $user;
                $_SESSION['email'] = $email; 
                $_SESSION['LoggedIn'] = 1;

                header("Location: websiteURL");
            } else {
                echo "Error 1";
                die();
            } 
    } else {
        echo "<pre>"; // dumps the array onto multiple lines instead of one
        print_r($_REQUEST);
        echo "</pre>";
        echo "Error 2";
        die(); 
    }  
} else {
    echo "Error 3";
    die();
}

?>
```

Here is the full output of the print_r($_REQUEST); :

```
Array
(
    [user] => username
    [pass] => password
    [PHPSESSID] => 5958246ece69dfdff197ec46e4771aac
)
Error 2
```

Comment: Here's the details to add: The full output of print_r($_REQUEST).

Comment: You might also want to add `$pass = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $pass);`.

Comment: Proverbial `session_start();` loaded somewhere? Why do I always have to ask that question when I don't see it, yet am sure it is, even though it's not shown. Silly me.

Comment: @Fred-ii- - it's in the base.php. Should I add it under the script as well, though?

Comment: `session_start();` must be inside all files used where sessions are used.

Comment: Since the 'base.php' is included in the 'login.php', would I still need to add it to the actual 'login.php'?

Comment: If `base.php` is loaded for all files and `session_start();` is in there, it's ok. No need to add it again.

Comment: YOU'RE ALL GOING TO LAUGH AT ME. I USED THE WRONG COLUMN NAME. FUUUUUUUUUUU. I FIXED IT. THANK YOU ALL FOR YOUR HELP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is obviously failing

```
if($result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE `user`='".$user."' AND `pass`='".$pass."'") {...}
```

Is `$con` a valid connection?

Try putting backticks around the table name `users`.

You should do some error checking. Take a look at the output of

```
// You can add this to the Error 2 block (for testing.. not production use)
echo mysqli_error($con);
```

This will give you an "idea" of what's going wrong, and will help others much in helping you.

Comment: If he is getting the result `Error 2`, the query is not even running. One of the variables `$user` and `$pass` are `empty()`. `Error 1` would show if the query is having a problem.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn I think if that was the case, he would be getting `Error 3`

Comment: Yea, my fault, I see the tabbing screwed up. Appears that the `empty()` calls are tabbed to match the `Error 2`.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn - I just did some empty checking and it appears that both the username and password are being requested, but not working with the script.

Comment: @Th3MadCreator, what do you have in the database? You probably have the plaintext password in the database, not the hash.

Comment: To add to this, I would capture the full query string in its own variable, and then log out the query to see exactly what is being run. Then copy / paste that into your db client and get some info about what is coming back

Comment: @JonathanKuhn - I have the hash in the database. I ran a separate script to verify that I was also using the correct password.

Comment: @Th3MadCreator I made a couple updates to my answer. Check it out, if you get a mysqli_error, let us know what it is :)

Comment: So you're going to love this. I used the wrong column name. I used 'pass' and in the DB it's 'password'. Didn't even catch it. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @Th3MadCreator Would have definitely seen that with mysqli_error ;p worthy of accepted answer? lol

Comment: @Shredder - That's how I found it. Thank you tremendously. Chose it for accepted answer (I think).

Answer (score 1):

Try using session_start(); before any of the includes. This ensures the server session is started